# 404 error in Laravel routing with changing parameter order

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, routes, http-status-code-404

There is a strange problem in my Laravel routing. When I use this url everything goes perfect:

```
Route::get('properties/{product}', 'ProController@getpro');
```

But while I want to change the order like below, I get a 404 not found page:

```
Route::get('{product}/properties', 'ProController@getpro');
```

What is the problem?

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/pizza-lake-dariusbury/properties 404 (Not Found)

I'm using Laravel installer version 2.0.1

Comment: There is no `laravel 2.0.1` version

Comment: @AyazShah laravel installer version i mean

Comment: Do you have another `ProController` routes declared?

Comment: @Laerte yes i have another one that take two parameter just :: Route::get('{prod?}/{prod_size?}', 'ProController@name')

Comment: You should try to invert the routes when declaring and test if works. But the problem may be that the engine could not determine if a url matches with one route or another. For example: /product/1/properties, could perfectly fit this route:prod/prod_size.

Comment: @Laerte yes excactly true, thanks very much . i have problems in routing adding parameters

Comment: Just to register this, I'll post as an answer, ok?

Comment: @Laerte  alles ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using two routes that take generic parameters, Laravel could have problem to match a URL to a route. For example: `/product/1/properties`, could perfectly fit this `{prod?}/{prod_size?}`.

To fix this, I suggest that you add some prefix to the route, to identify them:

```
Route::get('routename1/{product}/properties', 'ProController@getpro');
Route::get('routename2/{prod?}/{prod_size?}', 'ProController@name');
```

Then `routename1/1/properties` would never fit `routename2/{prod?}/{prod_size?}`.

Then Laravel would be able to match perfectly the URL parameters to the route.